# Django aggregate max and sort human

Tags: django, sorting, aggregate

In models.py

```
no = models.CharField()
...
```

How build queryset with aggegate Max

```
model.objects.values().annotate(max=Max('no'))
```

If no can be: 1, 55, 56-1, 56-2, 125, 8 etc., ie not number, but string. 
Can i make human sorted?

Now values get from:

```
1
125
5
55
56-1
56-2
8
... max = 8
```

I want:

```
1
5
8
55
56-1
56-2
125
...max = 125
```

Comment: sort order is controlled by the database and basically you have bad data for this kind of sorting.  one approach would be to 'left pad' the strings with zeroes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad ...though this will be more complicated in your case because you have the `-1` suffix on some rows too. But basically you need to manipulate the field values in the db (in the query) and sort on the manipulated value... you can then use `extra` in the Django ORM to do the same thing. But get it working in SQL first

Comment: give a little more info, my experience is still small, to understand this

Comment: eg in MySQL you'd do `SELECT LPAD('no', 6,'0') AS padded FROM mytable ORDER BY padded ASC;` i.e. instead of sorting on your actual field you transform the field value (using various string functions) into something sortable and then sort on the transformed value

Comment: i`m sorry, i thought about it, sort before aggegate. But how to do it? May be a little example. Thanks you for your attention

Comment: your values are bad for sorting, you need to make new values that you can sort on

Comment: thanks Anentropic, i will look for other ways